# What window message applications receive on screen text size change

Tags: windows, user-interface

A user has an ability to change a scale of displayed text (via *Settings → Display → Change the size of text, apps and other items* on Windows 10, for example).

What window message should I process to be aware of such changes?

I have a stuff which size depends on actual font height. However, size ajustments are time consuming so I would prefer not to perform them on each `WM_PAINT` arrival.

Comment: Checking the metrics of your font on `WM_PAINT` should be pretty easy and quick.

Comment: @MarkRansom, so I need to stash an initial font height in `WM_CREATE`, then compare it with the actual one in `WM_PAINT` and, if they differ, make ajustments and update the stashed height, right?

Comment: I'm not sure you'll have the proper font available in `WM_CREATE`, so I'd just wait for the first `WM_PAINT` to do the initial measurement. But I think you have the idea.

Comment: @MarkRansom, well, since there is no more answer, I hope your solution is the only approciate one in my situation. So it would be good if you publish your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: There's no need for me to post an answer, you have all the information you need. Besides I'm curious to know if there's such a message myself.

Comment: Did you try using Spy++ ?

Comment: @Abyx, I hooked Windows Explorer window as the one that responds to rescaling. However [its log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOJYT.png) has no trace of any event that is specific to rescaling. The log was started just before rescaling and stopped jus after rescaling.

Comment: @Abyx, I tested on WinXP SP2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it [WM_DPICHANGED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn312083(v=vs.85).aspx)?

> Sent when the effective dots per inch (dpi) for a window has changed. The DPI is the scale factor for a window.
>    - The window is moved to a new monitor that has a different DPI.
>    - The DPI of the monitor hosting the window changes.

Comment: This event is not fired on Windows XP. Is there any universal solution?